# Change value of variable in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, actionlistener

I have a program where I create animals - cats, dogs and cows. I'm making an interface with a button that will list all of the objects that I create in a JTextArea. I also want a button that re-sets the variable "height" for all *dogs* when I press it.

I created a method called `eraseHeight()` in my dog class:

```
public int eraseHeight(){
    height = 0;
    return height;
}
```

In my class called **Graphics** I added a listener to the button erase that creates an object of this class:

```
class heightListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for(Animals v : array){
            if(v instanceof Dog){
                ((Dog) v).eraseHeight();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This must be completely wrong because my method only returns 0 and does not set anything, but I do not know how to call for a method that will erase a variable that is already stored in my array. Help appreciated :)

Comment: that looks about right. what is not working?

Comment: Make sure you're also updating the JTextArea text or else the Dogs' heights may be reset, but the JTextArea's values are not linked to the dogs so you'll have to set the text again.

Comment: well, you are setting the value of height to zero, and then returning height, which is zero ... and that is what you are getting, right? for certainty, maybe try this.height=0

Comment: And it seems strange that your check does *instanceOf Dog* to then cast to a completely unrelated (?) type *Aktie* instead?!

Comment: Sorry.. Aktie is what the class is called in my program, I simplified and translated. It's supposed to be Dog

Comment: Please clarify your problem. What are you trying to do and what is not working?